# Loop through every column name and value in MySql reader?

Tags: c#, mysql

Below I am using a MySqlDataReader and would like to know how I could loop through all the column names and the values, and add them to a `<string,string>` dictionary by key and value of the column name and column value? My code is below of how I use the reader.

```
protected bool TryLoadPlayerData(PlayerConnection playerConnection, string sso)
{
    try
    {
        SetPlayer(playerConnection);

        using (var databaseConnection = Hariak.HariakServer.Database.NewDatabaseConnection)
        {
            databaseConnection.SetQuery("SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `auth_ticket` = @sso LIMIT 1;");
            databaseConnection.AppendParameter("sso", sso);


            using (MySqlDataReader reader = databaseConnection.ExecuteReader())
            {
                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    // loop through columns here...
                }
            }
        }

        Logger.Info("Loaded PlayerData for " + SelectColumn("username"));
        return true;
    }
    catch (Exception exception)
    {
        Logger.Error(exception, "Failed to load PlayerData for player.");
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: There is a built in mechanism for storing all the rows and columns - its called a `DataTable`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What i would do is just loop through all the FieldCount this allows you to get the index for each returning row and then just add them to the dictionary using `GetName` and `GetValue`

```
protected bool TryLoadPlayerData(PlayerConnection playerConnection, string sso)
{
    try
    {
        SetPlayer(playerConnection);

        using (var databaseConnection = Hariak.HariakServer.Database.NewDatabaseConnection)
        {
            databaseConnection.SetQuery("SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `auth_ticket` = @sso LIMIT 1;");
            databaseConnection.AppendParameter("sso", sso);


            using (MySqlDataReader reader = databaseConnection.ExecuteReader())
            {
                Dictionary<string, string> dictionary = new Dictionary<string, string>();
                for (int i = 0; i < reader.FieldCount; i++)
                    {
                        dictionary.Add(reader.GetName(i), reader.GetValue(i));
                    }
            }
        }

        Logger.Info("Loaded PlayerData for " + SelectColumn("username"));
        return true;
    }
    catch (Exception exception)
    {
        Logger.Error(exception, "Failed to load PlayerData for player.");
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Accepted.